# How can I execute js function calls when my .js file is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function calls:

```
Layout.Controls.sidebar(Button.Add);
Layout.Controls.sidebar(Button.Init);
Layout.Controls.printScreen(Button.Add);
Layout.Controls.theme(Button.Add);
Layout.Controls.theme(Button.Init);
```

I put the calls inside of a .js file.  But how can I make it so these calls are executed when the .js file is loaded?

Comment: they will execute when you load in the js file.

Comment: If you import the script using a script element, then it is executed when it's loaded. Maybe there is something missing in your question ?

Comment: Oh I had to put them inside a function() { } call or something like that. I didn't know the calls would be executed when loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All scripts that you put in your page using `<script>` elements are executed in order, as soon as they're available.

That's the same for inlined scripts (`<script>alert(1);</script>`) or scripts imported from external files (`<script src="somefile.js"></script>`).

You don't have to do anything special : your code in the external js file will be executed as soon as it's loaded.